# Cant render Sidebar in React

Tags: reactjs, render

I followed a tutorial and did everything the same way but React does not render my App.

Can anyone see what the problem is? I just get a blank page with no elements.

This is my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import App from './App';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

root.render(
   <App/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);



reportWebVitals();
```

This is  my App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import Sidebar from "./Sidebar";

function App() {
    return(
        <div>
            <Sidebar>
                <a href="/">Home</a>
                <a href="/products">Products</a>
                <a href="/pricing">Pricing</a>
                <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
            </Sidebar>
        </div>
    );


};


export default App;
```

This is my Sidebar.js file

```
import React from "react";
import "./Sidebar.css";

function Sidebar(props) { 

    return(
        <aside className="Sidebar">
            <nav className="Sidebar-nav">
                {props.chidren}
            </nav>
        </aside>

    );

};

export default Sidebar;
```

This is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to add, that it works, when I use a topMenu and bottomMenu attribute instead of children and put it the a-tags to the sidebar as attributes:

in Sidebar.js I changed this code part:

```
        <nav className="Sidebar-nav">
            {props.topMenu}
        </nav>
        <nav className="Sidebar-nav">
            {props.bottomMenu}
        </nav>
```

In App.js I changed this code part:

```
<Sidebar topMenu={
                <div>
                     <a href="/">Home</a>
                     <a href="/products">Products</a>
                </div>   
            }
            bottomMenu={
                <div>
                     <a href="/pricing">Pricing</a>
                     <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
                </div>
            }
            />
```

Now it works. But why does it not work with children ?

Comment: Only this is needed `root.render(<App/>);`

Comment: show us the html

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: no there are no errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your index.js to this

```js
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: How does it fix the issue?

Comment: this helped to see the tags in the browser elements but the page is still blank